# PDF fonts not visible properly

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript

I am using ghostscript 8.63 to split the pdf document as individual pages.
Problem is for some pdf's in the splitted pdf document fonts are overlapped (black patches). observed for verdana-bold fonts text.

I copied all the fonts required for gostscript to -sFontPath directory, and ghostscript also opening the verdana, verdana-bold font files but in splitted file fonts are not proper.

Comment: This is not really a programming question, voting to move to superuser.com. Also, some screen shots would be helpful to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use version 8.63. That's more than 2 years old already.

The [most recent version is 8.71](http://www.ghostscript.com/releases/).

In between the two releases a **lot** of improvements and bugfixes have happened, *especially* in relation to PDF input file processing and PDF outputting (and both of these features are used when you use Ghostscript to split PDFs into individual pages).